# finding some value for a martingale

Tags: probability

I got $(X_n)$ being iid random variables. $P(X_n=0)=1/2, P(X_n=1)=1/3, P(X_n=-1)=1/6.$

and $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$

I wanna find $\theta \in (0,1)$ that $M_n = \theta^{S_n}$ is a martingale w.r.t. natural filtration of $(X_n).$

I have $E[M_n | F_{n-1}] $= $E[\theta^{S_{n-1}}$ . $\theta^{X_n}] = \theta^{S_{n-1}}$ . $E(\theta^{S_n}) $ which should be equal to $\theta^{S_n-1}.$

I don't know how to get the expectation of the $\theta^{X_n}$

Comment: The expectation of $\theta^{X_n}$ is just found using the usual formula for expected value of a function of a discrete random variable with known PMF: multiply $\theta^k$ by the probability that $X_n = k$, and sum over all values $k$ that $X_n$ can take (just three values here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are some typos in the formula 
$$E[M_n | F_{n-1}] = E[\theta^{S_{n-1}}\cdot \theta^{X_n}] = \theta^{S_{n-1}} E(\theta^{S_n});$$
it should be 
$$
E[M_n | F_{n-1}] = E[\theta^{S_{n-1}}\cdot \theta^{X_n}\color{red}{\mid F_{n-1}} ] = \theta^{S_{n-1}} E(\theta^{\color{red}{X}_n})
$$
and using the fact that $X_n$ has the same distribution as $X_1$, we are reduced to find $\theta$ such that $\mathbb E\left[\theta^{X_1}\right]=1$. 
The latter quantity can be computed as follows: for a fixed $\theta$, the random variable $\theta^{X_1}$ takes the value $1$ with probability $1/2$, $\theta$ with probability $1/3$ and $\theta^{-1}$ with probability $1/6$ so we are at the end reduced to solve a second degree equation.